# Websockets and Ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I'm using NodeJS with express to create a Websocket application with WS on EC2(Ubuntu).
I have the following code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8090 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

Also, I added a "custom tcp rule" to the port 8090 and anywhere(0.0.0.0/0)

After I run:
wscat --connect http://myipaddress:8090

I got:
error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED myipaddress:8090

Am I forgetting something in Ec2 Configuration or code?

Greetings

Comment: You are trying to connect with `http://myipaddress:8090` but it should be `ws://myipaddress:8090`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to connect using the HTTP protocol. Try running `wscat --connect ws://myipaddress:8090`.